# LibSSL1.0.0 Throwing Errors

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation

Whenever I try to do any package manipulation - stuff like `apt-get install` or `apt-get update`, etc. - I keep getting errors related to `libssl1.0.0`. I've tried various things online to no avail.

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` returns the following:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libssl1.0.0
 libssl1.0.0:i386
```

I'm relatively new to Linux, and I am running `12.04`. Does anybody have potential solutions?

Output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a`: http://pastebin.com/cKzmq7sg

Output of `sudo apt-get install -f`: http://pastebin.com/yA35qcBz

Output of `apt-cache show libssl1.0.0:i386 | head -2`:

```
W: Unable to locate package libssl1.0.0:i386
E: No packages found
```

Comment: post the full output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/yA35qcBz

Comment: And also post the full output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` in your question.

Comment: I've updated the question.

Comment: And also post the output of `apt-cache show libssl1.0.0:i386 | head -2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to forcely remove the unconfigured `libssl1.0.0:i386` package,

```
sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libssl1.0.0:i386
```

Then fix the dependencies,

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: post the output of `uname -m`

Comment: Output: `x86_64`

Comment: Letus discuss here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11833/room-for-avinash-raj-and-whoever-wants-to-make-company

Comment: Try this command `sudo dpkg -P --force-all --force-remove-reinstreq libssl1.0.0:i386` and then `sudo apt-get install -f`